# Granular Security in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Consider a database with the following structure:

**Tables**

[dbo].[Customer], [dbo].[Address], and [dbo].[Report]

**Schemas**

[dbo] and [Reporting]

What I would like to be able to do is to have a principal (could be user or role) be able to manage views (CREATE, ALTER, DROP) in the Reporting schema only.  Further, this principal would need SELECT permission on all of the tables in the dbo schema (to support the creation of views in the Reporting schema).  The last thing I would like to be able to do is give INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE permissions to the Report table only in the dbo schema.

Is this something that is possible?  I have yet to find the right combination of permissions.  I can use any combination of users, roles, etc. in order to accomplish this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the [GRANT Shema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-schema-permissions-transact-sql) permissions on my made-up `ReportUsers` domain group, I can assign SELECT permissions as follows:

```
GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA :: dbo TO [domain\ReportUsers];
```

For the Reporting schema, that can be tackled in a few ways. Do you want to give them full control over the schema? Is it just for creating views?

Comment: A couple of things.  First, I think I was on the right path.  I had tried a command similar to the first one you mentioned but it did not work initially.  The problem was due to a *bonehead* mistake in that I forgot to add the user to the DB role that I was granting the permission to.  Second, the second statement did not work for me.  It looks like I have to grant the CREATE VIEW permission at the database level and then grant the ALTER permission to a specific schema.  I think this will work as I want.  Anyhow, I have marked your answer as the accepted solution.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Once you figure it out, feel free to update my answer with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

> What I would like to be able to do is to have a principal (could be
>   user or role) be able to manage views (CREATE, ALTER, DROP) in the
>   Reporting schema only.

To be able to `create`/`alter`/`drop` views in Reporting schema only you should grant `CREATE VIEW` permission in the database and `ALTER` permission on the schema:

```
grant CREATE VIEW to user1;
grant ALTER on schema::Reporting to user1;
```

Note, you **CANNOT** execute this one:

```
 GRANT CREATE VIEW ON SCHEMA :: Reporting TO user1;
```

You'll get the following error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near 'CREATE
>   VIEW'.

This is because CREATE VIEW can be granted on database level only.

The same thing you'll find in the BOL article: [CREATE VIEW (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql):

> Permissions
>
> Requires `CREATE VIEW` permission **in the database** and `ALTER` permission
>   **on the schema** in which the view is being created

When you grant these 2 permissions, they are aslo sufficient to `alter` and `drop` any view in the schema `Reporting`, so if you wanted your user just to be able to `create`/`alter`/`drop` views in Reporting schema only you've done.

There is no need to have `SELECT` permission in `dbo` schema if all you want is to make him create views.

If you want to make your user be able to `SELECT` from views created (in schema `Reporting`) you should grant `SELECT` on schema Reporting:

```
grant select on schema::reporting to user1;
```

> The last thing I would like to be able to do is give INSERT, UPDATE,
>   and DELETE permissions to the Report table only in the dbo schema.

```
grant insert, update, delete on dbo.Report to user1
```

To be able to update / delete using filter you should also grant `select` on `dbo.Report`, so your third grant should be this one:

```
grant select, insert, update, delete on dbo.Report to user1
```